# Connected components of $\mathbb{R^w}$ in box topology

Tags: general-topology, connectedness, box-topology

How can I know about all $\mathbb{R^w}$  in box topology? How can I separate $\mathbb{R^w}$ in box topology in to components and path components?in uniform topology I can separate using the path connected convex open balls but I have no clue in box topology. please help..